# Terraform use split/substring key values

Tags: terraform

I have a requirement to create users via Terraform. I'm trying to use a `map` type approach to make adding/removing people easier for non-Terraform people.

I need values for `email`, `name`, `first_name`, and `last_name`

These are all present in the initial `email` field, so I would like to avoid adding additional values to duplicate, but I am unsure if I can use split/substrings of this `email` value in other `for_each` values

Something along these lines (this does not work as is)

```
resource "user" "user" {
  email                = each.value["email"]
  name                 = each.key
  first_name           = "${element(split(".", each.key)[0])}"
  last_name            = "${element(split(".", each.key)[1])}"


  for_each = {

    "FIRSTNAME.LASTNAME" = {
      email    = "firstname.lastname@domain.tld"
    }
    
    "BOATY.MCBOATFACE" = {
      email    = "boaty.mcboatface@example.com"
    }
    
    "CHUCK.NORRIS" = {
      email    = "chuck.norris@example.com"
    }
  }
}
```

Is splitting a `map` value on the fly like this possible?
Or do I need to add the extra key/values to each use for `first_name` and `last_name`?

What I would like to do is avoid having to do this

```
resource "user" "user" {
  email                = each.value["email"]
  name                 = each.key
  first_name           = each.value["first_name"]
  last_name            = each.value["last_name"]

  for_each = {

    "FIRSTNAME.LASTNAME" = {
      email      = "firstname.lastname@domain.tld"
      first_name = "firstname"
      last_name  = "lastname"
    }
    
    "BOATY.MCBOATFACE" = {
      email    = "boaty.mcboatface@example.com"
      first_name = "boaty"
      last_name  = "mcboatface"
    }
    
    "CHUCK.NORRIS" = {
      email    = "chuck.norris@example.com"
      first_name = "chuck"
      last_name  = "norris"
    }
  }
}
```

Appreciate any insight/help anyone can provide

Many thanks

Comment: Your code is not even valid TF code. So what's exactly is happening? It does not run, due to all the syntax errors?

Comment: Sorry, my very bad attempt to use pseudo code

Comment: What error message do you see when you try to use the code in your first example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure If I understand you correctly but this is my interpolation.

```
variable "emails" {
    description = "List of emails that will feed name, first_name and last_name values in order to create accounts"
    default = ["firstname.lastname@domain.ltd", "boaty.mcboatface@example.com"]
}

resource "user" "user" {
  for_each = var.emails

  email                = each.key
  name                 = join(" ", [split(".", each.key)[0], split(".", each.key)[0]])
  first_name           = split(".", each.key)[0]
  last_name            = split("@", split(".", each.key)[1])[0]
}
```

EDIT:
`last_name` was wrong, corrected by: Ravichandran

Comment: I think the `last_name` will not get the expected value from `split(".", each.key)[1]`.  Possibly this can be retrieved as `split("@", split(".", "firstname.lastname@domain.ltd")[1])[0]`

Comment: Yep, my bad. I'm editing.